# How to do dll injection

Tags: go, winapi, hook, inject, dll-injection

I tried to do DLL injection with Go, but failed.

I am preparing the DLL file that I will inject with C++. Is that the problem?

DLL prepared with C++:

[image]

I tired to inject the DLL file with Go like this:

[image]

But when the `CreateRemoteThread()` function worked, Notepad++ was closed.

[image]

Why did I fail?  Where did I go wrong?

TestD.dll code:

```
#include "pch.h"    

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH STARTED", L"DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH TITLE", MB_RETRYCANCEL);
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Go InjectApp code:

```
var dllPath = "C:\\Users\\RecaiCingoz\\go\\src\\TestD.dll"
    className := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Notepad++")
    hwnd := win32services.FindWindowW(className, nil)
    fmt.Println("Process HWND", hwnd)

    _, processID := win32services.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    hProcess, _ := win32services.OpenProcess(win32services.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(processID))

    baseAddress, _ := win32services.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, len(dllPath), win32services.MEM_COMMIT, win32services.PAGE_READWRITE)
    err := win32services.WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, uint32(baseAddress), []byte(dllPath), 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    modLib, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    loadLib, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(modLib, "LoadLibraryA")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    hRemoteThread, _, err := win32services.CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nil, 0, loadLib, baseAddress, 0)
fmt.Println(hRemoteThread)

}
```

CreateRemoteProccess func:

```
func CreateRemoteThread(hprocess HANDLE, sa *syscall.SecurityAttributes,
    stackSize uint32, startAddress uintptr, parameter uintptr, creationFlags uint32) (HANDLE, uint32, error) {
    var threadId uint32
    r1, _, e1 := procCreateRemoteThread.Call(
        uintptr(hprocess),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sa)),
        uintptr(stackSize),
        startAddress,
        parameter,
        uintptr(creationFlags),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&threadId)))

    if int(r1) == 0 {
        return INVALID_HANDLE, 0, e1
    }
    return HANDLE(r1), threadId, e1
}
```

How can I do DLL injection in Go? Can anyone help me?

[WriteProcessMemory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pl7t.png)

> Edited to added

Codes have been updated.
Current code.

Application crash continues. (Notepad++)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    dllPath, _ := syscall.FullPath("DTest.dll")

    className, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString("Notepad++")
    hwnd := w32.FindWindowW(className, nil)
    _, processId := w32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

    var dwMemSize int
    var hProc w32.HANDLE
    var err error
    var lpRemoteRem, lpLoadLibrary uintptr

    hProc, err = w32.OpenProcess(w32.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(processId))
    if err == nil {
        dwMemSize = len(dllPath) + 1
        lpRemoteRem, err = w32.VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, dwMemSize, w32.MEM_RESERVE|w32.MEM_COMMIT, w32.PAGE_READWRITE)
        if err == nil {
            err = w32.WriteProcessMemory(hProc, uint32(lpRemoteRem), []byte(dllPath), uint(dwMemSize))
            if err == nil {
                modulKernel, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
                lpLoadLibrary, err = syscall.GetProcAddress(modulKernel, "LoadLibraryA")
                if err == nil {
                    hTread, _, err := w32.CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, uint32(lpLoadLibrary), lpRemoteRem, 0)
                    if err == nil {
                        w32.ResumeThread(hTread)
                        w32.WaitForSingleObject(hTread, syscall.INFINITE)
                        _, err := w32.GetExitCodeProcess(hProc)
                        if err == nil {
                            w32.CloseHandle(hTread)
                        } else {
                            panic(err)
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                } else {
                    panic(err)
                }
            } else {
                panic(err)
            }
        } else {
            w32.VirtualFreeEx(hProc, lpRemoteRem, 0, w32.MEM_RELEASE)
            panic(err)
        }
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }

    w32.CloseHandle(hProc)

}
```

[Error message i see when i llok at the event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1xJD.png)

Comment: What package or type is `win32services`?

Comment: Custom package. Package with win32api dll and procedures.

Comment: What is the return value `loadLib` of `GetProcAddress`? Have you performed error checking on the return value of each winapi? And I noticed that your dll version is x86, did you check the version of notepad++? It will fail if the versions do not match.

Comment: LoadLibrary return type: syscall.Handle - type Handle uintptr .  Return value: 140715276042240                                                                                        GetProcAddress return type uintptr. Return value: 140715276174480   I checked the notepad++ version x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LoadLibrary return type: syscall.Handle - type Handle uintptr . Return
> value: 140715276042240 GetProcAddress return type uintptr. Return
> value: 140715276174480

140715276042240 and 140715276174480 are truncated x64 addresses. The maximum address of x86 is 0xFFFFFFFF, which becomes 4294967295 after converting to decimal.

You use GO(x64 version) to compile the program, and use `uint32` to convert the address to x86 address. Finally, you get an invalid address. This is why notepad++ crashed.

Solution: Use GO(x86) to compile the program.

Comment: @Recai Cingöz Hi, please tell me if the answer useful to you?

Comment: sorry i got error again. I changed it to GOARCH=386 but the result did not change.

Comment: @RecaiCingöz `sorry i got error again` Do you mean Notepad++ crashed again?  Which api returned an error?  And what is the error?

Comment: i'm sorry. My English is not very good. yes Notepadd++ crashed again. I stopped trying. because I was so bored. I'm looking at other topics now. `I will look at this later`

Comment: @RecaiCingöz All right. Your code is useful to me. If you have any other questions, please feel free to let me know.